# Download content from Base64 source using JS

Tags: javascript, base64

I have Base64 stream and i wanted to download content as a file from that. I have tried below script.

`<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,[base64]" download="file.pdf">`

As per above code we have to specify the file type as well. But i wanted to get the file type from the 64 bit stream and download file as it is without hard coding file type because base64 stream could me pdf or docx in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: when you create the `href` base64 data (what you've shown as `[base64]`) - at that point, you would also know the file type - so don't hardcode the file type - if you don't understand this, then please show the method you are using to create the link href content

Comment: i`m getting this base64 from a service.so i don`t know the file type at any point.It could be docx or pdf

Comment: right, OK easy then ... you know it's one of two things ... a PDF will always begin with the characters `JVBERi` - which is Base64 of `%PDF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of a PDF file **always** begins with the string `%PDF`

in base64 this is `JVBERi`

So, you can inspect the first 6 characters of your base64 for `JVBERi` - if it matches, it's PDF, if it doesn't it's not PDF

Comment: Yes this can be used.Thanks @bravo. In addition to this is there any method to retrieve the file name that used to be encoded from base64 stream?

Comment: @lahiruk93 - base64 encoding of a file does not include a filename ... it's just the files contents encoded into base64 after all - so, no, there is no way to determine the filename from the contents - consider a filename called `foo.txt` with content `bar` .... base64 encoded `bar` is `YmFy` - which has no indication of the filename

Answer (score -1):

the mime type is not mandatory in the data uri. so you can just omit it. but all the same, i guess you have to deal with the download filename so you should be able to deal with the appropriate mime type the same way.